# How to slide a panel from right to left using bunifuTransition in c#

Tags: bunifu

I have `bunifutransition1` that slides my `mainpanel` from left to right upon clicking `showbutton`. (It shows the hidden `mainpanel`.)

What I want is, when I click `closebutton`, the `mainpanel` will slide from right to left (to hide the `mainpanel` again). It seems that bunifuTransition does not have an animation that reverses the animation of VertSlide or HorizSlide.

What should I do to slide my `mainpanel` from right to left to hide it again on my form?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue but upon reading your question the answer finally became prevalent in my mind. The solution here is to stop using `BunifuTranisition` altogether and go for the good ol' for loops and the other mods, puns intended.

```
int originalWidth = panel.width;
int menuClicksIndex = 0;

private void beginTransition()
{
    if (menuClickIndex % 2 == 0)
    {
        //This executes on the first click
        for(int i = originalWidth-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
           // Loops from original width to 0
            panel.Width = i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= originalWidth; i++)
        {
            panel.Width = i;
        }
    }
    menuClickIndex++;
}
```

This works for me but it glitches on the way back from left to right. So a mixed version with `BunifuTransitions` for the opener and the `for loop` for the closer would be the ideal solution here.

UPDATE 1: It seems as if while changing the width of the panel from 0 to say, 350, the content inside the panel doesn't render until the height is set to the max, but while decreasing the height from 350 to 0, the content is already rendered and so it seems smooth to close but cluttery to open, hence probably explaining why BunifuTransition is unable to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here.

Just go bunifu transition properties
Open or dragdown DefaultAnimation. Find this option in menu ("Side Coeff") It Show value of 
X and Y {X=1, Y=0} . You just change this value  {X=-1, Y=0}.
Then Start your project and check. Your slider sliding left to right. :)

Keep enjoy.
Regards,
Haris Ali

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `bunifuTransition1.HideSync(guna2Panel1);` before any code on event button click!

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnFuncionario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuPages2.Transition.SlideCoeff = new PointF(1, 0);
        bunifuPages2.SetPage(1);
    }

    private void btnCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuPages2.Transition.SlideCoeff = new PointF(-1, 0);
        bunifuPages2.SetPage(0);
    }
```

i used it, its work!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**